# Why does the header in this template have a shadow?

Tags: html, css

I am looking at the following template:

```
http://mojothemes.cosmo-coder.com/dual-flow/Dark/services.html
```

Can someone explain why there is a shadow area at the base of the

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
```

I have looked for a long time with firebug and I cannot see anything that would create the shadow. Not box-shadow on that element. I am interested in using this template but before I use it I would like to find out how this shadow appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shadow is not in #header-wrapper, it's in #page-title

```
#page-title {
  ... 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it's the shadow from `<div id="page-title">` moved up

Answer (score 1):

Its not actually the div "header-wrapper" that has the shadow at the base,

Its the below div "page-title" that has the box shadow property.

Also both uses CSS gradient Also

Answer (score 1):

i hope i'm answering correct to you....

```
box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
```